# Replacing a values but not shows full data in python Array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
cur_data=np.array([['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5'], ['6'], ['7'], ['8'], ['9'], ['10'], ['1']])

rep_data=np.array([['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5 and above'], ['5 and above'], ['5 and above'], ['5 and above'], ['5 and above'], ['5 and above'], ['Single']])

d=pd.DataFrame(cur_data)
d.replace(cur_data,rep_data,inplace=True)
```

Getting output:

[image]
[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Please help me out with this issue

Comment: You are replacing values in an empty data frame, first fill it up with `cur_data`, then the replacement works.

Comment: pls consider "d=pd.Dataframe(cur_data)"

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong here:

```
d=pd.DataFrame()
```

change to

```
d=pd.DataFrame(cur_data)
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if solved, else get back with the issue.

Comment: I have edit the post. please help me about replacing a array numeric values

Comment: You can run the same code now, it's working. Check.

Comment: On my machine I get 
```Out[22]:
             0
0            2
1            3
2            4
3  5 and above
4  5 and above
5  5 and above
6  5 and above
7  5 and above
8  5 and above
9       Single
```

Comment: can you print(len(d)) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220290/discussion-between-govinda-raju-and-sayan-dey).